# Integrating Webcam and Fingerprint support into OpenERP

Tags: webcam, fingerprint, odoo

I want to extend the medical module of OpenERP to include webcam and fingerprint support. I would be using OpenERP on a local network not connected to the internet. Please what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: "Webcam and fingerprint support" seems a bit vague to me. Do you mean that you want to attach a photograph and fingerprint scan to a patient record as image files? It would probably be helpful to link to some description or source for the medical module. All I could find was [this list of features](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/features/medical.html).

Comment: What I want to do is instead of uploading an image when creating a patient, I could simple click on a button that activates the webcam, takes the person's picture and then saves it.

Comment: I agree with @DonKirkby, what you're asking for is pretty vague on how to integrate. not to mention that the thymbra medical modules have been migrated to tryton for quite some time now under the name health gnu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flash which will access your webcam and you can capture image and save it to a predefined location. Search croflash on sourceforge.net that will help you