# How to implement web-cam in OpenERP

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, odoo

I want to implement web-cam in OpenERP. web-cam integration. Anyone give me idea how to and where to implement web-cam coding. I want to create widget for that like barcode.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do, with a use case. I have no idea what "web cam coding" is in the context of OpenERP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrating Webcam and Fingerprint support into OpenERP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608904/integrating-webcam-and-fingerprint-support-into-openerp)

Answer (score 2):

On web client or on gtk, you should create different implementations, for web-client you must create a new widget i dont manage the the new JS framework but theorically this is the way.

Regards/